# Signed Zero: Change -0 to 0

Tags: javascript, signed

I just came across this problem and I would like to know:

What is the best practice for changing a `-0` to a normal `0`? This baffles me as to why there would be a method for setting the signed value but no clear cut way to change it to a normal `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's supposed to be a logical integer, force integer context by bitwise or-ing with 0:

```
var x = -0;
console.log(x | 0);  # Produces 0
```

For all other integer values, this is a no-op (aside from possibly speeding up code in certain browsers by guaranteeing the value is integer for JIT optimizations; this is a common trick to inform the browser you intend integer behavior used by JS cross-compilers), and since -0 is not a legal integer value, it converts it to plain 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just test it and reassign it.

```
if (var === -0) {
    var = 0;
}
```

This will also do the assignment if `var` contains positive 0, because `0 === -0`, but there's no harm in that.